# I have failed to import my csv file into python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, spyder

trying to import a csv file from my desktop

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\u1703025\Desktop\Debts.csv',sep =',')

Getting this error

```
runfile('C:/Users/u1703025/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/u1703025/.spyder-py3')
  File "C:\Users\u1703025\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 2
    df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\u1703025\Desktop\Debts.csv',sep =',')
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: This has **nothing to do with** reading CSV. The problem is already in the part where you try to give the path to the file. It happens because the `\U` and `\u` parts have special meaning inside a string literal. Please read the linked duplicate for more. Also, what you are trying to do is **not called** "importing". It is important to understand proper terminology for things, in order to be able to search for information yourself.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `r` before path

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\u1703025\Desktop\Debts.csv',sep =',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\u1703025\\Desktop\\Debts.csv',sep =',')
```